# Getting R to write to .txt with carriage returns

Tags: r

I am having R sample from data 100 times then write those to a text file that my boss can then load into Excel.  I currently have R doing the samples but when it comes to writing I can't get the results to be in a single column just different rows.  I have tired writeLines, write.table, write, and write.csv.  The closest I can get is using write.table.

```
Dataset <- read.table("clipboard", header=FALSE, sep="", na.strings="", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
ThePath = ""
*Replace with where you want it to save
P = .25
*Put the Percentage Value you want to use here
X = round(nrow(Dataset)*P)
Boot1 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot2 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot3 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot4 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot5 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot6 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot7 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot8 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot9 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot10 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot11 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot12 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot13 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot14 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot15 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot16 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot17 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot18 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot19 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot20 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot21 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot22 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot23 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot24 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot25 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot26 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot27 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot28 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot29 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot30 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot31 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot32 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot33 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot34 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot35 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot36 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot37 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot38 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot39 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot40 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot41 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot42 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot43 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot44 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot45 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot46 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot47 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot48 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot49 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot50 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot51 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot52 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot53 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot54 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot55 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot56 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot57 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot58 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot59 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot60 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot61 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot62 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot63 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot64 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot65 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot66 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot67 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot68 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot69 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot70 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot71 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot72 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot73 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot74 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot75 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot76 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot77 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot78 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot79 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot80 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot81 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot82 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot83 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot84 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot85 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot86 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot87 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot88 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot89 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot90 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot91 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot92 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot93 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot94 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot95 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot96 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot97 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot98 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot99 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
Boot100 = sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X))
write.list(data.frame(sum(Boot1), sum(Boot2), sum(Boot3), sum(Boot4), sum(Boot5), sum(Boot6), sum(Boot7), sum(Boot8), sum(Boot9), sum(Boot10), sum(Boot11), sum(Boot12), sum(Boot13), sum(Boot14), sum(Boot15), sum(Boot16), sum(Boot17), sum(Boot18), sum(Boot19), sum(Boot20), sum(Boot21), sum(Boot22), sum(Boot23), sum(Boot24), sum(Boot25), sum(Boot26), sum(Boot27), sum(Boot28), sum(Boot29), sum(Boot30), sum(Boot31), sum(Boot32), sum(Boot33), sum(Boot34), sum(Boot35), sum(Boot36), sum(Boot37), sum(Boot38), sum(Boot39), sum(Boot40), sum(Boot41), sum(Boot42), sum(Boot43), sum(Boot44), sum(Boot45), sum(Boot46), sum(Boot47), sum(Boot48), sum(Boot49), sum(Boot50), sum(Boot51), sum(Boot52), sum(Boot53), sum(Boot54), sum(Boot55), sum(Boot56), sum(Boot57), sum(Boot58), sum(Boot59), sum(Boot60), sum(Boot61), sum(Boot62), sum(Boot63), sum(Boot64), sum(Boot65), sum(Boot66), sum(Boot67), sum(Boot68), sum(Boot69), sum(Boot70), sum(Boot71), sum(Boot72), sum(Boot73), sum(Boot74), sum(Boot75), sum(Boot76), sum(Boot77), sum(Boot78), sum(Boot79), sum(Boot80), sum(Boot81), sum(Boot82), sum(Boot83), sum(Boot84), sum(Boot85), sum(Boot86), sum(Boot87), sum(Boot88), sum(Boot89), sum(Boot90), sum(Boot91), sum(Boot92), sum(Boot93), sum(Boot94), sum(Boot95), sum(Boot96), sum(Boot97), sum(Boot98), sum(Boot99), sum(Boot100)), file=ThePath, row.name=FALSE, col.name=FALSE sep="/r")
```

I have tried to use write.list and just write but nothing is getting the output I am looking for.  I also tried making it into a csv and also space as a sep and they all turn out like this

25026689/r19976650/r13281740/r15783000/r36507540/r15811400/r15799460

or with , or spaces where the /r are.
I am looking for something like this

25026689
19976650
13281740
15783000
36507540
15811400
15799460

I know my code is super bruteforceish and can be done way cleaner and easier with counts and loops but I am still learning most of the coding.

Comment: To have carriage return use `\r` not `/r`. But I think Excel uses commas `,`, semicolons `;` or tabs `\t`.

Comment: Zomg thank you.  I read that then looked at my code and didn't see a difference.  Then it clicked.

Comment: You could take away a bit of the leg work by doing something like: `result <- replicate(100,sum(sample(Dataset$V1,X)))` then use `write.csv(result,"filename.csv")` A `csv` file can be opened straight into Excel then.

Comment: if you just want your boss to be able to read it into excel, why not write a csv that he can open directly?

Comment: @Glen_b Well, If in the time of my internship I can get the code to allow the input and output the way I am looking then that will work better.  Currently this will need to have to be run around 60 times as there is 60 different datasets.  The data out of the database doesn't come exactly clean and my boss is less savvy (I'm a 4 out of 10 on programming savvy) than I am.  So this way he can just copy the column of data then run this in R, then copy the text document output into a new excel file.  Not exactly efficient as you have to do this 60ish times but it gets the job done for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a data frame with a single row. In Excel this will be represented in the same way (i.e. one row, instead of one column).

The solution is to create a single vector that contains your bootstrap values.

This is the perfect time to get acquainted with `sapply` or its close cousin `replicate`:

```
boot <- data.frame(
  boot = replicate(100, sum(runif(100)))
)
head(boot)
      boot
1 50.84482
2 49.57098
3 52.75195
4 52.20751
5 48.55071
6 50.76622
```

Easy, isn't it?

---

Now your code turns into:

```
Dataset <- read.table("clipboard", header=FALSE, sep="", na.strings="", 
                      dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
ThePath <-  ""
#Replace with where you want it to save
P <- .25
#Put the Percentage Value you want to use here
X <- round(nrow(Dataset)*P)


boot <- data.frame(
  boot = replicate(100, sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X)))
)
write.csv(boot, file=="your_file_name", row.names=FALSE)
```

**Disclaimer: untested - I don't have your data**

Comment: Wow, thank you for the insight on making it not so ugly and much much cleaner.

Comment: Damn, I should refresh before writing comments. +1 Btw - shouldn't the write.csv call only have one `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so when it writes to the csv there isn't a count column?