# Exporting the dataframe to text file

Tags: export-to-csv

Is there a way to write a data frame to text file and also give position and length of columns while writing.

```
df <- data.frame(
    col1 <- c(1, 2, 3),
    col2 <- c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
    col3 <- c("place1", "place2", "place3")
)
```

I want to export the df into text file where col1 has length = 1 and position = 1; col2 has length = 20 and position = 2 and col3 has length = 60 and position = 21

Comment: Please include a concrete code example. With an example input data frame, and an example output file. Thank you!

Comment: df has 3 columns. column 1 contains values 1,2,3; column 2 contains name1, name2, name3 and column 3 contains place 1, place 2, place 3                                                           output text file should contain first row as 1name1  place1   as the requirements are  column 1: length is 1 and position should be 1; column 2: length 7 and position 2; column 3 length 20 and position 10

Comment: Thank you! I hope you don't mind but I edited you post. Unfortunately, I still don't know how your output should look like. Please provide an exact example of the expected output for `df`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want, but you might take a look at `write.table()`

```
write.table(df, file="df.txt")
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You may also have a look at [how to write into .txt file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338726/how-to-write-into-txt-file-in-r) and [Getting R to write to .txt with carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503412/getting-r-to-write-to-txt-with-carriage-returns). There, they suggest that one can, and in fact should in some circumstances, consider `fwrite`.

**EDIT 2**
If your output txt should look like

```
1--name1--place1
2--name2--place2
3--name3--place3
```

you need

```
write.table(
    df, file="df.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep="--", quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: in sas, we used put statement, eg: data_null_; set input: file 'test.txt'; put @1 col1 $1.          @2 col2 $20.                                                                                                                                                    @ 21 col3 $60.                                                                                                                                                      what would be the equivalent in python

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't know how your file should look like. However, I have edited my answer. Please check, and mark as correct answer and give it an upvote if it is correct.

Comment: Hi MacOS, the output in text file looks like as follows:    <br/>         1name1 &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;    place1<br/>
2name2   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;   &nbsp;   &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; place2<br/>
3name3  &nbsp;   &nbsp;    &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  place3 <br/>                                                                                             basically, between col1 and col2, no space as col1 is of length 1 <br/> and position of col2 is 2. Also, since col2 is of length 20 col3 starts from 21 position.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not follow you. You should add this information to the question and be precise in what you want. Also, please format everything accordingly. Thank you!